# Transferring Node system to new server getting configure is not a function error

Tags: node.js, express, npm, server

I am transferring my code from one server to a new server and I keep getting the same error. I am not sure why as these servers are the same and should be almost identical, the code works on Server A but on server B I get this error.

> *./router* is empty, Never needed

**Error**

```
TypeError: configure is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/mm3/controller.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

**My node server file**

```
"use strict";
var fs = require('fs');
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
var archiver = require('archiver');
var server = require('http').Server(app); // not sure what this is ?
var configure = require('./router');
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var nodePardot = require('node-pardot');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var rp = require('request-promise');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3331;
var router = express.Router();
configure(router);
var password = 'd.0s../d9';
var userkey = 'hgsydghdupi';
var emailAdmin = 'fs@fee.co.uk';

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '100mb',extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '100mb'}));
app.use(express.static('/public'));
app.use(express.static('/js'));
app.use(express.static('/tmp'));
app.use(express.static('/img'));
app.use(express.static('/css'));
app.get('/mm3', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname +'/index.html')
});

app.listen(port);

console.log('Test server started! At http://localhost:' + port); // Confirms server start

app.post('/mm3/savePhotos', function (req, res) {
    var folder = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 20);
    var photos = req.body;
    var counts = 0;
    var callback = function(counts){
        if(counts < photos.length){
            saveBase64(photos[counts],folder,counts,callback);
        }else{
            var response = {"folder":folder, "photos": photos.length};
            res.send(response)
        }
    };
    saveBase64(photos[counts],folder,counts,callback);
});

app.post('/mm3/downloadZip', function(req, res){
    var photos = req.body;
    var out =  photos[0];
    var test = out.split('/');
    var loc  = test.pop();
    var end =  test.join('/');
    var outName = '/var/www/html' + end +'/MockUp.zip';
    var output = fs.createWriteStream(outName);
    var archive = archiver('zip', {store: true });
    var zip = function(photos, f){
        for(var t = 0; t < photos.length; t++){
            var file = 'mockUp'+ t +'.jpg';
            var from = '/var/www/html' +  photos[t];
            archive.file( from, { name: file });
        }
        f();
    };

    output.on('close', function() {
        var photos = req.body;
        var out =  photos[0];
        var test = out.split('/');
        var loc  = test.pop();
        var end =  test.join('/');
        res.send(end + '/MockUp.zip');
    });
    archive.on('error', function(err) {
        throw err;
    });

    archive.pipe(output);
    zip(photos, f);
    function f(){
        archive.finalize();
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you npm install?

Comment: Fist thing I tried

Comment: var configure = require('./router'); is this file exist. please verify file name and strict case

Comment: If you don't need `./rooter`, remove `configure(router);`

Comment: @FarhanYaseen yes the file exist

Comment: @TGrif, yes you are right. I kept it in as I may of used it at a later point